# Navigation drawer with navigation component problems

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make an Clinic app and I have some problem with that.
I have an navigation drawer in my app. 
I used the ready project from here: https://github.com/umangburman/Navigation-Drawer-With-Navigation-Component

I have added some fragments but I don't know how to change two things:

1. When I go to e.g. visitsFragment -> addVisitFragment and I click on back arrow in top-left corner, 
   I come back to default fragment, but I want back to visits Fragment
2. Another problem is that when I do things from 1. (When I'm in addVisitFragment and I click on back arrow) fragment is not being replaced but put on top of the previous one. I know that because when I click on some places, dialog opens etc

Can somebody look at it? This is my project if you need it: https://filebin.net/w1pnrpnet4ofjs61

Hope You figure it out

edit:
If all that stuffs are a big problem it will be awesome if somebody show me how to change back arrow to working open navigation drawer icon.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, try to override onbackpressed() function and navigate to visits Fragment.

Comment: I think that in my case onbackpressed() is called when I click back button in my phone, but when I click on back arrow onSupportNavigateUp() is called

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
 fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Let me know if  you need full source code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that. I'm using that when I change a fragment, but thats not the point.

Comment: When you changing fragment it will store previous fragment in stack and just call onBackPressed() while you are clicking left arrow

Answer (score 0):

Other way is if you are using custom toolbar then add

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp" 
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
               android:id="@+id/imgDrawer"
               android:visibility="gone"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

then in your Drawer activity file

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)


        toggle.syncState()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can't you just put it on my source code?

Comment: I have code without navigation controller and it is working fine! Do you need that?